# Pass SSIS parameters from C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I have an SSIS package which has some Project.params set.

How do I pass values for those parameters to the SSIS package via C#?

I'm trying the following:

```
const string pkgLocation = @"export.dtsx";
var app = new Application();
var pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

var results = pkg.Execute();
```

This returns a failure, with Errors collection containing "The variable "$Project::connString" was not found in the Variables collection. The variable might not exist in the correct scope."

So I tried adding

```
var param = pkg.Parameters.Add("connString", TypeCode.String);
param.Value = "test"; 
var results = pkg.Execute();
```

But this throws a DtsGenericException.

Comment: Look at the documentation for the `LoadPackage` method. That's an overloaded method and there should be one that accepts 5 parameters, that would be one way of doing this. Oh, this is a project parameter. I haven't started a package via .net that's using the project deployment model. I suspect you're going to need more code as you'll need to reference the project's ispac for it to be aware of the project level entities.

Comment: The error mention the variables collection and the parameters... have you tried to add it to the variables? `pkg.Variables.Add("connString", false, "Project", "test");` (assuming that your variables's namespace is "Project")

Comment: Try using the Package object's Execute overload method which takes in a collection of Variables. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtscontainer.execute.aspx

Comment: I [couldn't figure it out](https://gist.github.com/billinkc/c7ae8aa3b69cbab20d3a). I hang my head in shame. :( I *was* able to get package level parameters passed in but couldn't get the project scoped ones. I assume it's something with the `Project` class consuming an ispac but couldn't figure out how to do something with a `PackageItem`

Answer (score 6):

I think I got it. The trick is to deserialize your ispac file (VS builds this but you *can* do it via [msbuild](https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/)) into a `Project` object. The Project object allows us to set project level parameters (as well as access project level connection managers).

From there we will need to get a reference to the specific package we want but it will be a `PackageItem`. PackageItems can't run but they do have a Package property we will use to instantiate the `Package` class which *does* have an `Execute` method

```
   public static void final()
    {
        string isPacPath = @"C:\sandbox\so_31812951\so_31812951\bin\Development\so_31812951.ispac";
        string packageName = "Package.dtsx";
        Application app = new Application();
        Package pkg = null;

        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff930196(v=sql.110).aspx
        Project proj = null;
        PackageItem pi = null;
        DTSExecResult results;

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Run an SSIS package that has a Project parameter
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        proj = Project.OpenProject(isPacPath);

        // Yes, I can see the packages in there
        foreach (var item in proj.PackageItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Project {0} contains package {1}", proj.Name, item.StreamName));
        }

        //Also able to see the project level parameters
        foreach (Parameter item in proj.Parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Project {0} contains parameter {1} type of {2} current value {3}", proj.Name, item.Name, item.DataType, item.Value));
        }

        // assign a value to my project level parameter
        proj.Parameters["ProjectParameter"].Value = 10;

        // Get the package from the project collection
        pi = proj.PackageItems[packageName];

        // Convert the package into a package object
        pkg = pi.Package;

        // This is how we specify a package parameter value
        pkg.Parameters["PackageParam"].Value = 777;

        results = pkg.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine(results);
    }
```

This assumes you have an SSIS project called `so_31812951` which compiled to an ispac located at C:\sandbox\so_31812951\so_31812951\bin\Development\so_31812951.ispac  This project has a single package called Package.dtsx. There will be a Project level parameter, Int32, named `ProjectParameter` as well as a package level parameter, Int32, named `PackageParam`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for figuring this out. Wish there was a more straightforward way to do this!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you will need to utilize the ParameterValue class.

```
var parameters = new ParameterValue[somelength];
parameters[index] = new ParameterValue()
{
     Name = "parameter name",
     Value = "parameter value"
}
```

The report service will have a method:

```
SetExecutionParmeters(parameters, language).
```

I am assuming you are loading the report, "export.dtsx", into SSIS and executing via the report service.

Comment: Nope, it's SSIS not SSRS.