# Loading package metadata from IS Catalog

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

I am looking for a way to load package metadata from SSIS Catalog.

When working with `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime` namespace we can load SSIS package using the simple method

```
Application app = new Application();
Package pak = app.LoadFromSqlServer(path, server, user, pass, null);
```

`LoadFromSqlServer` returns `Package` object that has properties for accessing package metadata. 
For example, we access package Executables simply by accessing object property `pak.Executables`

When working with SSIS Catalogs and Projects in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices` namespace, to access the package we use:

```
PackageInfo myPackage = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"]
           .Folders["MyFolder"]
           .Projects["MyProject"]
           .Packages["MyPackage.dtsx"];
```

But, `PackageInfo` does not contain equivalent properties/methods to the ones form `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package` class.

How would I "convert" `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo` to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package` so I could access package metadata?

Comment: Possibly [relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812951/pass-ssis-parameters-from-c-sharp) to get you further along